# java: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, java-11, ioexception, runtime-compilation

During code compilation in Intellij, getting the Java: "java.lang.RuntimeException: "No additional logs are forthcoming.  Since I started using Java 11 version, this problem has been occurring.

Tried deleting the file /.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/compile-server and the invalidate cache option, but no luck.

Comment: Any details in idea.log and build.log? See [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085). Does it help if you re-install the JDK?